# Issues with overriding Devise controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controllers, overriding

I'm trying to override a Devise controller to have some minor changes, for example adding a flash message when requesting a confirmation email for an unregistered email address.

I tried to override `Devise::ConfirmationsController`[1](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/59cd9e72b9cb2ffc98d41b1bbad04c7849a97a2e/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb) this way:

```
# app/controllers/confirmations_controller.rb
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController

  include Devise::Controllers::InternalHelpers # tried to add this, no success

  def create
    self.resource = resource_class.send_confirmation_instructions(params[resource_name])

    if successfully_sent?(resource)
      respond_with({}, :location => after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
    else
      respond_with(resource)
    end
  end

end
```

I think I added the route correctly:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :confirmations => "confirmations" }
```

My controller method gets called, however it raises this exception:

```
NoMethodError in ConfirmationsController#create

undefined method `successfully_sent?' for #<ConfirmationsController:0x007fa49e229030>
```

In my overridden controller, I just copied the code of `Devise:: ConfirmationsController#create`, which itself calls `successfully_sent?(resource)`

The `successfully_sent?` method is defined in `InternalHelpers` [2](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/2a5ad4664b679bc4c020f113982ac2ccd7a2d31c/lib/devise/controllers/internal_helpers.rb), this is why I tried to add `include Devise::Controllers::InternalHelpers`

This is not the first time I try to override a Devise controller, and this is not the first time I fail. I always managed to get a workaround, but I'd like to understand what I'm missing... Thanks in advance for your help!

[EDIT]
Devise is in version 1.4.9
Rails is 3.0.10

Comment: What version of Devise are you using? Did you actually copy the code using 'bundle open devise' (or equivalent) from the version of Devise you have installed, or just from somewhere on the internet? I don't see successfully_sent? defined anywhere in my version of Devise.

Comment: Have checked the routes using rake routes

Comment: @Kyle: Indeed that's my newbie's mistake! I was looking at the last committed version on Github, which is not the one I'm using... I will answer the question thanks to your help, so... thanks!

Comment: @JudeArasu: not a route issue, I properly added the custom Devise route in the `routes.rb` file and my controller gets correctly called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, thanks to the help of Kyle in my question's comments, I will write the correct answer to this beginner's mistake.

**Instead of looking at my own version of Devise to override the controller, I was simply looking at Devise's Github repository. Since the controller I was trying to override had changes between my version and the last committed one, the helper method I was trying to use was simply not defined in my version...**

As indicated by Kyle, you can use `bundle open devise` to look at the code of the gem you're actually using, or you can look at its version number with `gem list devise` and find the code for this release on Github (for Devise they set the tags for each release so that you can browse the code for release 1.4.9 by selecting the corresponding tag).

Doing this, I would have overrode my controller's `create` method with the following code instead:

```
def create
  self.resource = resource_class.send_confirmation_instructions(params[resource_name])

  if successful_and_sane?(resource)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :send_instructions) if is_navigational_format?
    respond_with({}, :location => after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
  else
    respond_with_navigational(resource){ render_with_scope :new }
  end
end
```

which uses `successful_and_sane?` and not `successfully_sent?` ...

To conclude this answer, there may be a better way of adding a flash message to this method than overriding it. jarrad is advising to use `around_filter`, but I can't get it to work yet and I'm unsure I can still change the rendered view after I yielded it from the filter method... Comments welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

This may not help you understand why overriding the Devise controller is failing, but it will keep your code DRY in that you do not need to copy the code from `Devise::ConfirmationsController#crete`

So, if you just want to set a flash message, look at [Filters for ActionControllers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#after-filters-and-around-filters)

Specifically, look at the Around Filter:

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  around_filter :my_custom_stuff, :only => :create

  private

  def my_custom_stuff
    # do your thing here...
  end
end
```

Comment: I will write another answer which better match my issue, but I like your suggestion and we'll be using it, so thanks too! (and +1 for this helping tip).

Comment: Well, I can't find how to add the flash message from within the around_filter. I'm wondering if this is possible. When I call `yield` in the around filter method, the view gets rendered, so I don't see (yet) how I could change the content to add the flash message. If you can help me on this, that would be nice.